# Simple question about the traslation from french to english

Tags: algebraic-geometry, translation-request

Goodmorning.  I'm reading an article by Arnaud Beauville talking about the surfaces of general type. I've found this term and i'm not sure about the translation: What does it mean a " pinceau de courbes"?

Comment: Could it be pencil of curves? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pencil_%28mathematics%29

Comment: @NickyHekster has the right answer (which should be written as an answer!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Nicky Hekster has rightly said, this translates as *pencil of curves*.

In case evidence is required for this claim, [here](http://www.math.ens.fr/~wittenberg/genusone.pdf) is a monograph by O. Wittenberg whose French title is

> Intersections de deux quadriques et pinceaux de courbes de genre 1

with the English subtitle

> Intersections of two quadrics and pencils of curves of genus 1

Comment: Note that the original French, which refers to a paintbrush, makes a lot more sense! I always wondered why we call this thing a pencil... http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pinceau

Comment: @hunter: I've always wondered about "paintbrush" --- why is that more descriptive of a 1-dimensional linear system? I would be glad to hear your interpretation!

Comment: It's not a great interpretation -- just that the bristles are curves that aren't perfectly aligned as in a product but are twisty and fringe-y... it's no better a word than "bundle," but that one is taken.

Comment: @hunter: thanks! I like that image. As you say, it certainly makes more sense then "pencil".